# How can I import a java swing class into the GUI builder of intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, intellij-idea

I have a eclipse project with some swing GUI form in it, and now I want to try IntelliJ for this project.
Those swing forms were built under window builder plugin in eclipse, and I've only got one single *.java file.

Is there any plugin I can use to modify these swing forms under IntelliJ?

Comment: *"Is there any plugin I can use to modify these swing forms under intellij ?"*  GUI builders will not 'accept' (allow you to import to the GUI builder) any code that is hand written, or written with another GUI builder.  That's one of a variety of reasons that people advise against using a GUI builder at all.  I recommend you learn how to layout components by using the standard layouts and ***no*** GUI builder.

Comment: Well, if there is not such a plugin, modifying it manually would be the only choice. I can handle that but I really don't want to do that .....

Comment: *"modifying it manually would be the only choice"*  Good luck if the GUI builder used `GroupLayout`.  Most people consider the code from doing so to be so hard to modify that it would be faster to rewrite the GUI from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Form Snapshot feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-opening-forms.html) to capture the structure of a dialog in your running application and save it as a .form file in the format of the IntelliJ IDEA IDEA UI Designer.

Note that the UI Designer does not support all possible Swing layout managers; you would not be able to edit the form if it uses an unsupported layout manager.