# IntelliJ Binding class to form

Tags: java, windows, forms, swing, intellij-idea

I have src files, but there is no form file. When i run program there is GUI and i want to edit it. When I create form and copy code to binded class, GUI editor still does not show forms.

Simply: I have Primary class

```
    I need Primary:
                   - Primary class
                   - Primary.form (that shows forms)
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem or question is. Please follow the stackoverflow's guide lines for posting a question.

Comment: How can i get GUI in editor from class. This is my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I import a java swing class into the GUI builder of intellij?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138207/how-can-i-import-a-java-swing-class-into-the-gui-builder-of-intellij)